# Configuring MUI Components selector API with Babel in Meteor "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null" on project start

Tags: reactjs, meteor, material-ui, babeljs, emotion

I have a Meteor React project, for which I have added Material UI v5 ([installation instructions](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/)), which comes with Emotion for CSS-in-JS styling:

```bash
$ meteor create --react meteor-react-mui
Created a new Meteor app in 'meteor-react-mui'.

$ cd meteor-react-mui

$ meteor npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
+ @emotion/react@11.11.1
+ @emotion/styled@11.11.0
+ @mui/material@5.14.17
added 79 packages from 99 contributors and audited 193 packages in 51.3s
```

I would like to use the [components selector API](https://mui.com/system/styled/#how-to-use-components-selector-api), so I installed `@emotion/babel-plugin` as required:

```bash
$ meteor npm install @emotion/babel-plugin
+ @emotion/babel-plugin@11.11.0
updated 1 package and audited 194 packages in 1.643s
```

...and then I added the configuration, as described in above docs, into my `.babelrc` file:

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@emotion",
      {
        "importMap": {
          "@mui/system": {
            "styled": {
              "canonicalImport": ["@emotion/styled", "default"],
              "styledBaseImport": ["@mui/system", "styled"]
            }
          },
          "@mui/material/styles": {
            "styled": {
              "canonicalImport": ["@emotion/styled", "default"],
              "styledBaseImport": ["@mui/material/styles", "styled"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

However, now when I start the project, I have this error:

```bash
$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/.../meteor-react-mui ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started HMR server.                        
/.../.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.../dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:218
      throw error;
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
    at InputFile.resolve (/tools/isobuild/compiler-plugin.js:403:61)
    at packages/babel-compiler.js:574:23
    at Array.some (<anonymous>)
    at requireWithPrefixes (packages/babel-compiler.js:569:26)
    at requireWithPath (packages/babel-compiler.js:487:14)
    at resolveHelper (packages/babel-compiler.js:459:24)
    at resolveHelper (packages/babel-compiler.js:450:21)
    at packages/babel-compiler.js:432:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at walkHelper (packages/babel-compiler.js:431:10)
    at walkBabelRC (packages/babel-compiler.js:417:24)
    at BabelCompiler.BCp._inferHelper (packages/babel-compiler.js:514:17)
    at BabelCompiler.BCp._inferFromBabelRc (packages/babel-compiler.js:359:14)
    at BabelCompiler.BCp.inferExtraBabelOptions (packages/babel-compiler.js:333:10)
    at BabelCompiler.BCp.processOneFileForTarget (packages/babel-compiler.js:209:10)
    at packages/babel-compiler.js:123:25
```

Here are my dependencies in `package.json`:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.7",
    "@emotion/babel-plugin": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.17",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^1.2.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

Meteor release version in `.meteor/release`:

```bash
METEOR@2.13.3
```

And Meteor packages versions in `.meteor/packages`:

```bash
meteor-base@1.5.1             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.1.0       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.16.7                   # The database Meteor supports right now
reactive-var@1.0.12            # Reactive variable for tracker

standard-minifier-css@1.9.2   # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js@2.8.1    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.8.0                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers
ecmascript@0.16.7              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code
typescript@4.9.4              # Enable TypeScript syntax in .ts and .tsx modules
shell-server@0.5.0            # Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command
hot-module-replacement@0.5.3  # Update client in development without reloading the page


static-html@1.3.2             # Define static page content in .html files
react-meteor-data       # React higher-order component for reactively tracking Meteor data
```

Note: if I use the `--typescript` template (instead of the defaut `--react` one as shown above), I have the same issue, but with a slightly different error message:

```bash
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
    at InputFile.resolve (/tools/isobuild/compiler-plugin.js:403:61)
    at packages/babel-compiler.js:574:23
    at Array.some (<anonymous>)
    at requireWithPrefixes (packages/babel-compiler.js:569:26)
    at requireWithPath (packages/babel-compiler.js:487:14)
    at resolveHelper (packages/babel-compiler.js:459:24)
    at resolveHelper (packages/babel-compiler.js:450:21)
    at packages/babel-compiler.js:432:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at walkHelper (packages/babel-compiler.js:431:10)
    at walkBabelRC (packages/babel-compiler.js:417:24)
    at TypeScriptCompiler.BCp._inferHelper (packages/babel-compiler.js:514:17)
    at TypeScriptCompiler.BCp._inferFromBabelRc (packages/babel-compiler.js:359:14)
    at TypeScriptCompiler.BCp.inferExtraBabelOptions (packages/babel-compiler.js:333:10)
    at TypeScriptCompiler.BCp.processOneFileForTarget (packages/babel-compiler.js:209:10)
    at packages/babel-compiler.js:123:25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like simply using the **full name** of the `@emotion/babel-plugin` package in the `.babelrc` Babel configuration file solves the issue for Meteor build:

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@emotion/babel-plugin", // Use full name, instead of just "@emotion"
      {
        // Etc.
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

In a normal React and Babel stack, the short name `@emotion` in the Babel configuration is actually [normalized](https://babeljs.io/docs/options#name-normalization) automatically to that full name, hence the Material UI documentation provides only the short name:

> Babel has a name normalization phase [which] will automatically add these prefixes when loading [plugin] items.
>
> [...]
>
> - `babel-plugin`/`babel-preset` will be injected as the package name if only the `@`-scope name is given.
>
> Input: `"@scope"` / Normalized: `"@scope/babel-plugin"`

Unfortunately, it looks like the Meteor `babel-compiler` wrapper package [re-implements this logic](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release/METEOR%402.13.3/packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js#L388-L397), but only the most simple part:

```js
prefixes.push("@babel/plugin-", "babel-plugin-");
// ...
prefixes.push("");
// ...
inputFile.resolve(prefix + id, controlFilePath))
```

Hence it is safer specifying the actual full name of the Babel plugin, instead of relying on name normalization.

---

Note: BTW, while the build now works, I still had an issue displaying the web page in the browser, with this message in browser console:

> Uncaught Error: Component selectors can only be used in conjunction with @emotion/babel-plugin, the swc Emotion plugin, or another Emotion-aware compiler transform.

I was using the components selector API like this:

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material"; // Import from MUI instead of from @emotion, e.g. to benefit from theme prop

const StyledDiv = styled("div")({
  // Some style...
});

const StyledParent = styled("div")({
  [StyledDiv]: { // Use the actual component as a selector
    // Some other style...
  }
});
```

Because of the import of `styled` function from the parent package `@mui/material` instead of the more specific `@mui/material/styles` as mentioned in the Babel config, the latter could not catch the import to transform. So I just needed to add the missing import path to the configuration as well:

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@emotion/babel-plugin",
      {
        "importMap": {
          "@mui/system": {
            "styled": {
              "canonicalImport": ["@emotion/styled", "default"],
              "styledBaseImport": ["@mui/system", "styled"]
            }
          },
          "@mui/material/styles": {
            "styled": {
              "canonicalImport": ["@emotion/styled", "default"],
              "styledBaseImport": ["@mui/material/styles", "styled"]
            }
          },
          "@mui/material": { // Add the missing import path
            "styled": {
              "canonicalImport": ["@emotion/styled", "default"],
              "styledBaseImport": ["@mui/material", "styled"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

...and now everything works!